# Change Appearance of Boolean Values on Infragistics UltraGrid

Tags: winforms, checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

By default, boolean values appear as checkboxes in a cell on the Ultragrid that are either checked (true) or unchecked (false). Is there a way to simply display this as text, such as "True" or "False", 0 or 1, or even "Yes" or "No"? I'm just trying to display boolean values. Checkboxes on the grid give a user the false impression that they can modify the data by attempting to check or uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by handling the `InitializeLayout` event and using a `ValueList`:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    var l = e.Layout.ValueLists.Add("MyBooleanValueList");
    var trueVal = l.ValueListItems.Add(true);
    var falseVal = l.ValueListItems.Add(false);
    l.DisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ValueListDisplayStyle.DisplayText;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["AmIHere"].ValueList = l;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it had to be easy.

Comment: I just noticed, and this is more of a technicality, but the True and False values are now displayed as a combobox within the cell that can be altered. Is there anyway to hide the fact that the cell is now a dropdown box?

Comment: I'll have to play around with it. I'm on the train now so I don't have access.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without showing the dropdown arrow and without allowing the user to edit the boolean cell:

```
    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGridLayout layout = e.Layout;
        UltraGridBand band = layout.Bands[0];

        ValueList vl = new ValueList();
        vl.ValueListItems.Add(true, "True");
        vl.ValueListItems.Add(false, "False");

        UltraGridColumn boolColumn = band.Columns["Boolean 1"];
        boolColumn.ValueList = vl;            
        boolColumn.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
    }
```